# Cordova notification plugin's prompt method not triggering keyboard in iOS 8.x

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using [cordova notification plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md) to do alert/confirm/prompt in one of the hybrid mobile applications. Wherever the prompt method

```
    navigator.notification.prompt(message, promptCallback, [title], [buttonLabels], [defaultText])
```

is used the keyboard comes up automatically at times and it doesn't come at times. The user had to click inside the text box within the prompt dialog to trigger the keyboard manually. I did try searching SO regarding this issue and found no clues to resolve.

1. Hybrid app framework : Ionic
2. Plugin : org.apache.cordova.dialogs; version : 0.2.11
3. iOS : 8.1.2